# MySQL vs PostgreSQL with SSRS

Tags: mysql, postgresql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm setting up a Redmine server and I'd like to write SSRS reports against it, looks like I can do either PostgreSQL or MySQL for the database, does anyone know whether one or the other is easier to connect to with SSRS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since SSRS is capable of support [ODBC as the data source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159219.aspx) either database properly configured will be equally easy to connect to.